# Binding ObservableCollection to a listView programmatically

Tags: c#, listview, winrt-xaml

There are lot of question of how to bind an ObservableCollection to a ListView through XAML. I need though how to bind the collection to ListView programmatically. There are some questions that help but they still do not address exactly what I need.

I have these classes:

```
public class myTask
{
    public DateTime TaskDate { get;}
    public string   TaskName { get;}

}
public class myTaskList : List<myTask>
{
    public ObservableCollection<myTask> getMyTasks(DateTime d)
    {
        ObservableCollection<myTask> t = new ObservableCollection<myTask>
                        (this.Where(x => x.TaskDate == d).ToList<myTask>());
        return t;
    }
}
```

And I want to bind only the TaskName of the result of getMyTasks to a listview at runtime. I have tried this approach:

```
    ListView lv = new ListView();
    //assuming I declare myTaskList a static class
    lv.DataContext = myTaskList.getMyTasks(DateTime.Now); 
    var binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = lv;
    lv.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

That may only bind the results to the list, how do I only bind TaskName in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've finally found a solution that is applicable to my scenario.

It is possible to bind a field of an ObservableCollection data set of multiple fields to a listview. What we need to do is declaring a data template in the resource:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key='myTaskItemTemplate'>
            <TextBlock x:Name='ItemTaskName'
                                 FontSize='15' 
                                 HorizontalAlignment='Stretch'
                                 VerticalAlignment='Stretch'
                                 TextAlignment='Center'
                                 Text='{Binding TaskName}' />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then create the listview using the above template

```
ListView lv = new ListView { ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["myTaskItemTemplate"] };
```

and then create a binding with the source being the ObservableCollection Dataset bound to the ItemSourceProperty of the listview

```
    var t = myCalendarMonth.TaskList(d.theDate);
    lv.DataContext = t;
    var binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = t;
    lv.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

I am sure there may be a lot better solutions out there as I am very new to XAML but the approach discussed about seems to yield the results I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, it's impossible to know for sure what answer you need. But…

There does not appear to be a binding operation here at all. The binding code you show creates a circular binding (binding the `ListView` object's `ItemsSource` property to itself), which doesn't seem useful. More to the point, you should be able to accomplish what you want simply by assigning the `ItemsSource` property, and the `DisplayMemberPath` property:

```
lv.ItemsSource = myTaskList.getMyTasks(DateTime.Now);
lv.DisplayMemberPath = "TaskName";
```

No need to create a binding at all.